# PostgreSQL - Write loop that creates new tables based on select query

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

In concept this is simple. I'm constructing a new database. I have all of the tables I want to create in tb.table_build and I want to write a statement that creates new tables for each of the items in the table_build select query.

```
DO $$
DECLARE counterVariable integer;
        CounterMax Varchar(150);
begin
  for Countermax in (select table_name 
                     from table_build 
                     where build_type = 'Number')
  loop
    CREATE TABLE Countermax (
    LIKE template_text_input);
  end loop;
end;
$$;
```

I cannot pass the variable CounterMax into the Create Table statement.

Comment: You need [dynamic SQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN)

Answer (score 0):

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=3a662f985f1f059d86687dff0c704011)

```
create or replace procedure create_table()
as
$$
    declare  _sql text; _row_record record;
    begin
    for _row_record in
        select table_name from table_build where build_type = 'Number' loop
    _sql :=  format ('create table %s (like template_text_input INCLUDING ALL) ',_row_record.table_name );
    raise notice '%', _sql;
    execute _sql;
    end loop;
    end
$$
language plpgsql;
```

then call it:

`call create_table();`

Comment: Worked Perfectly!